# Obtener mensajes de fichero properties en label de select Spring

Tags: html5, jsp, spring, java-ee, taglib

Estoy internacionalizando una aplicacion web donde tengo un select con dos opciones

```
<td><form:label path="rol">Rol</form:label></td>
                <td><form:select path="rol">
                        <form:option value="USER" label="Usuario"/>
                        <form:option value="ADMIN" label="Administrador"/>
                    </form:select>
</td>
```

Y tengo dos ficheros properties (messages.properties y messages_en.properties) para pintar en pantalla esa informacion lo hago de esta forma

```
<spring:message code="label.phone" />
```

Pero no se como recoger los valores de ese fichero para pintarlo en los labels de una select. Los campos son los siguientes:

```
label.rolUsu=User
label.rolAdmi=Administrator
```

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de poner

```
<form:option value="ADMIN" label="Administrador"/>
```

puedes escribirlo así:

```
<form:option value="ADMIN"><spring:message code="label.rolAdmi"/></form:option>
```